# How to make this my first JQuery plugin work

Tags: jquery, function, plugins, queue, fade

Thanks to the comments below. Here is an updated question and code:

I have written two bits of code, a loader and sequential fade in. The loader works by adding the load class which with css displays a loading spinner.gif. Then removes the class and inserts an image.

The second fade's in a sequence of divs in order.

```
$.fn.myLoader = function() {
    $(this).addClass("loading").queue(function(next) {
        $(this).removeClass("loading");
        $(this).prepend('URL');
        next();
    });
};

$('#logo').myLoader();
```

and

```
$('.load').delay(5000).each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 250).css({
        opacity: 0.0,
        visibility: 'visible'
    }).animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    });
});
```

and the following markup:

```
<div id="logo"></div>
    <div class="load" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
    <div class="load" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
    <div class="load" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
    <div class="load" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
    <div class="load" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
    <div class="load" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
```

These work separately but I would like to merge the two so that the loader happens and once that has finished, loads the sequential images.

Please point out the errors of my way.

Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense... your loader doesn't load anything and it doesn't allow for a way to tell it to hide when something finishes loading, it just assumes that it's done in 200ms... Please give a more complete sample.

Comment: Also, [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) doesn't work like that.  It only affects items in the animation queue.

Comment: Kevin B: Thank, I'll re-write it. Let me know if make better sense. Christian Varga: THat's actually a mistake, sorry. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: dude, you cannot call $('#logo').myLoader with a callback argument, because your plugin doest not receive a callback as an argument.

Comment: Rodrigo - I need to read up some more. Cheers.